# Show products in a database based on category ID

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am able to achieve the desired affect showing products based on their category. However I feel the way I have gone about it isn't the best way. On the product page there are gaps between the products top and bottoms as [HERE](http://www.imagesocket.com/photos/guest/2563264) . I am presuming the gap is due to a error in my php code rather than the way I am laying out the html. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So to clarify I am wondering if the code used is the correct way to achieve this and if anyone can spot why the gap is there that would be perfect.

Just to clarify it is defiantly not a problem with css. No margin is applied and I want the black line completely gone. It should be all white.

Thank you and have a great new year.

**PHP code**

```
<?php
function get_posts($id = null, $cat_id = null) {
    $posts = array();

    $query ="SELECT  `products`.`id` AS  `name` ,  `products_cat`.`id` AS  `category_id` , `products`.`name` AS `title` ,  `description` ,  `price` ,  `sale` ,  `picture` 
FROM  `products` 
INNER JOIN  `products_cat` ON  `products`.`prod_id` =  `products_cat`.`id` ";

    if ( isset($id) ) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    $query .= " WHERE `products`.`id` = {$id}";
    }

    if ( isset($cat_id) ) {
        $cat_id = (int) $cat_id;
        $query .= " WHERE `products_cat`.`id` = {$cat_id}";
}

    $query .= " ORDER BY `products`.`price` DESC";

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    echo mysql_error();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
        $posts[] = $row;
        }

    return $posts;
}

function category_exists($field, $value) {
    $field = mysql_real_escape_string($field);
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `products_cat` WHERE `{$field}` = '{$value}'");

    echo mysql_error();

    return ( mysql_result($query, 0) == '0' ) ? false : true; 
}

?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<?php
include("../script/dbconnect.php");
include("../script/get_product.php");

$posts = get_posts(null, $_GET['id']);

?>

<div style="width:100%; height:150px; background-color:white;"><span style="font-family:saxMonoRegular; letter-spacing:2px; display:block; font-size:4.5em; text-align:center; padding-top:15px;"> Blog </span></div>

<div class="link" style="width:100%; background-color: white">
<?php
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    if ( ! category_exists('name', $post['name']) ) {
        $post['name'] = 'Uncategorised';
    }
    ?>      
    <ul class='featured'>

            <li class='headhighlight'><?php echo $post['title']; ?></li>  
            <li class='pricehigh'><?php echo $post['price']; ?></li>
            <li class='imagefeat'><img class='imagelink' src='<?php echo $post['picture']; ?>' alt='$name'></li>                
            </ul>   

    <?php
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: which gaps are you mean? Can you show on the image with red color these gaps?

Comment: There a image above in the link above. Its the black lines between the products top and bottom. http://www.imagesocket.com/photos/guest/2563264

Comment: I'm sorry to keep banging on about this, but please stop using the _deprecated_ `mysql_*` extension. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead (note the `i` in `mysqli_*`, it stands for _improved_)

Comment: @ Elias Van Ootegem Yeah I'm in the process of changing all the code over. Just want to get it fully working first. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iam not shure if iam understand right, but i would say its more a problem of CSS.

Try:

```
div.link {
  padding: 0px;
```

}

```
ul.featured {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Its defiantly not css. No margin is applied

Comment: Could you please provide an live example and explaine againe the problem. If i understood right, you like to have the black lines bettween the products but not the black lins above and below?

Comment: Hi, I want no black lines at all. The black lines are appearing and I don't know why. It should be a clean white background with no black lines.  Unfortunately I am running it off a localhost so can't provide a live example. To clarify I need the black lines gone completely and it to be all white.

Comment: Ok changed my anwer. Iam still shure that it is a css problem. The php and html are ok. There is somewehre in you css or in browser default css. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Comment: I am very surprised but that actually worked. Thank you very much green rover. Was more than confident it wasn't the css but we all make mistakes :) Once again thanks and happy new year!